# Missing artifact javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:3.0:provided

Tags: maven, pom.xml, buildpath

even though i have updated my pom file and added the jar file to my build path i am getting error in the console saying "Missing artifact javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:3.0:provided"

Comment: added all the jar in maven repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no jsp-api-3.0.jar. Perhaps you want to import jsp-api version 2.2 or servlet-api version 3.0.1

See:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.3.1/
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/